# iOS App upload to iTunes Connect - Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Cannot upload my App to AppStore - receiving email with "Invalid Signature". I try different ways.. Even create new id in Dev Centre and new App in iTunes Connect (new bundle id etc.). Still got this error. I also check many times for correct provision profiles and certificates - all ok in Xcode. What can I do? How can I fix this error?

One more thing: I still can upload another App - all fine. I use the same certificate for both Apps. So I think with certificates all ok..

Comment: Did you try to recreate production certificate?

Comment: I do not try. But why I must do this? Other Apps uploads well..

Comment: be sure to choose the right provisioning in code signing under Build Setting, sometime its just messed up

Comment: I choose right certificates and provision profiles. I double checked it. No, triple. Also I recreate profiles, even create new test App.. Still no effect. And as I said before - I can upload another Apps with this certificates.. Very strange. Very.

Comment: @DekelMaman you should add that as an answer! It really helped me!

Comment: @Computer_whiz123 happy to hear, have great coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something was with Bundle display name. I have "?" symbol. I remove it and App successfully uploaded.

Comment: When you say Bundle display name do you mean the key "Bundle name" inside you Info.plist file ? I am having the same issue you experienced and my app name also has a ? inside it.

Comment: This issue was happening to me due to the Product Name variable having a ? inside it. This meant it was rejected every time I uploaded it to Apple.

Comment: No, Michael, I have ? symbol in "Product name" in Build settings menu. You can fins it in Target settings (it also has General, Capabilities, Info etc. menus). so just remove ? symbol from name and all be fine. Very strange issue:) I spend really many hours on resolving this:(